# Obvious relation between Nul A and entries of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The book Linear Algebra and it's Applications by DC Lay states - "There is no obvious relation between Nul A and entries of A".

However I feel that there is an obvious relation between Nul A and entries of A since each element of Nul A is decided by the columns of A being linearly independent or dependent. If they are independent then Nul A consists of only the 0 vector while if they are dependent then they are weights of linear combination of the columns of A so that the sum is 0. Also this justification of mine seems to target elements of Nul A more than Nul A itself but I think that since Nul A is a set it's affected by it's elements hence it establishes a relation between Nul A and entries of A.

Isn't this then an obvious relation?

Comment: I guess that they want to say that you cannot get some elements of $\mathrm{Null}(A)$, in most cases, without any small calculation. This is different for the range of $A$, for example : you see directly that the columns of $A$ are in its image, without any calculation.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Can you explain your last sentence a bit more. I didn't understand the image part

Comment: When you have a matrix $A$, the columns of $A$ are elements of the image of $A$. Indeed, the $k-$th column of $A$ is exactly $A.e_k$ where $e_k$ is the vector with all coordinate zeros, except for the $k-$th which is $1$. So you "read" on the matrix some elements of its image (and in fact, the image is exactly the span of the columns of $A$).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you very much for explaining this :)